# My aloe vera is passed out, what can I do?

Tags: soil, aloe

I bought this aloe vera last week. As one of the leaves was falling (photo 2), I thought that if I tied them together with a string for a few days, this would help her to create strength to hold the leaves better.

In addition, I exchanged the soil that came with the plant for a mixture of earth + vermiculite + sand. Today, 3 days later, I removed what was holding the leaves and it doesn't look right at all. The leaflets at first were holding up, but now almost all of them have fallen (photo 3). What can I do?

[image]

Comment: How much water have you given it? Could be due to overwatering

Comment: @Sol I had put in a considerable amount of water, but I stopped! :(